# Exception running /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn/topology.py

Tags: apache-spark, cloudera, hadoop-yarn

Any time I try to run a Spark application on a Cloudera CDH 5.4.4 cluster, Yarn client mode, I get the following exception (repeated many times in the stack trace). The process continue anyway (it is a warning), but it is imposible to find something in the logs. How can I solve it?

```
15/09/01 08:53:58 WARN net.ScriptBasedMapping: Exception running /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn/topology.py 10.0.0.5 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn/topology.py" (in directory "/home/azureuser/scripts/streaming"): error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:485)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.ScriptBasedMapping$RawScriptBasedMapping.runResolveCommand(ScriptBasedMapping.java:251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.ScriptBasedMapping$RawScriptBasedMapping.resolve(ScriptBasedMapping.java:188)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.CachedDNSToSwitchMapping.resolve(CachedDNSToSwitchMapping.java:119)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.RackResolver.coreResolve(RackResolver.java:101)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.RackResolver.resolve(RackResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnScheduler.getRackForHost(YarnScheduler.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$resourceOffers$1.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$resourceOffers$1.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:263)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.resourceOffers(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverActor.makeOffers(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverActor$$anonfun$receiveWithLogging$1.applyOrElse(CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend.scala:131)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply$mcVL$sp(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:25)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.apply(ActorLogReceive.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.apply(ActorLogReceive.scala:42)
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ActorLogReceive$$anon$1.applyOrElse(ActorLogReceive.scala:42)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:186)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
    ... 32 more
```

Answer (score 3):

Faced the same problem while submitting a Spark job.

Most probably you don't have the "/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn/topology.py" file on the server you ran the Spark application. Or "/etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn/topology.py" is not available on one or more servers.

You can also resolve this problem by running the application in yarn cluster mode.

```
--master yarn-cluster
```

Comment: running the application in yarn cluster mode did not change the error, thus not resolving the problem

Answer (score 1):

chmod 755 /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn/topology.py

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution here: https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!searchin/cdh-user/Exception$20running$20$2Fetc$2Fhadoop$2Fconf.cloudera.yarn$2Ftopology.py/cdh-user/fte4IPjX8TU/0jUOGkXyCAAJ

Just add permissions to the user that launches the script on all the directories that form the path of the script (for reading and listing files).

Comment: I wish the post was more informative and not directing to a closed link.

Comment: I downloaded the client config files from Cloudera Manager and the folder names are different yarn-conf vs conf.cloudera.yarn .  Also, no execute permissions on topology.py .  I checked the cluster nodes and they have the expected names and permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue. you can  `scp /etc/hadoop/conf.cloudera.yarn Username@Host:/etc/hadoop` 
in the others datanode in your clusters  to your submit-shell computer and notices the permissions. Hoping it's fine for you.